# Don't show keyboard on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

Is there a way to NOT show the on screen keyboard on a website (loaded in safari) when a user clicks on an input type="text" field?  I have javascript written to popup a mini "keypad" which I'd like to use instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could try to set the input disabled (disabled="disabled"), show your popup on click and finally update the field content via JS.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but thanks for a solution that works.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change device behavior from your javascript or website. Especially not if the user has disabled javascript.

The only thing you could do is to allow for all inputs and do server side validation to exclude the phrases or characters you do not wish to be entered.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

In a custom app of course you can. In safari I don't think so.